# Returning error message to function expecting 'Box<dyn Error>'

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am new to Rust and am trying to propagate errors to be handled in the calling function. From the official rust book I read that Result 'Box< dyn Error>' is used to say capture any type of error but I haven't read far enough to understand how it actually works.

I have a function called:

```
fn foo() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Command::new("an_executable")
        .args(&["-p", path])
        .output()?;
    if condition {
        return Err("Error...");
    }
    // Do stuff, return String 
}
```

So can someone explain how I should be returning an error if a condition is met with that return type. Do i have to change the return type or just return something different. what would the RUST standard be in this scenario?

The current compilation error is that Err("Error...") mismatched with the return type

Comment: Did you try to follow the type literally and return `Err(Box::new(...))`? Can't check right now (I'm on mobile), but this might work.

Comment: @Cerberus Hi, thanks for having a look. I tried doing: Box::new(Err("error")) which gave the compilation error expected enum `std::result::Result`, found struct `std::boxed::Box`          And also tried out your example:which gave the error the trait bound `&str: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `&str`
note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::error::Error`rustc(E0277)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Let's focus on the absolute minimum reproduction of your issue:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn foo() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err("Error...")
}
```

The error returned by this code is:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     Err("Error...")
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found reference
  |
  = note: expected type `std::boxed::Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
             found type `&'static str`
```

It's saying that the function signature expected you to return an `Err` containing a `Box<dyn Error>`, but you actually returned an `Err` containing a `&str`. Since the types don't line up, the compiler throws an error.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the `Into` trait, which implements a conversion between `&str` and `Box<dyn Error>`:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn foo() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err("Error...".into())
    // `Err(Box::from("Error..."))` would also work
}
```

##### How it works

You may still be wondering what exactly that magic `.into()` call is doing behind the scenes.

First, let's see what happens if we just `Box` the `&str`:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn foo() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err(Box::new("Error..."))
}
```

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     Err(Box::new("Error..."))
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `&str`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::error::Error`
```

Again, this doesn't work because the types don't line up - it's expecting the `Box` to contain something that implements the `Error` trait, but if you [look at the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#implementors), you'll notice that `&str` is not one of the types that implements it. You need to wrap your string in a type that does implement `Error`:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StrError<'a>(&'a str);

// Error doesn't require you to implement any methods, but
// your type must also implement Debug and Display.
impl<'a> Error for StrError<'a> {}

impl<'a> fmt::Display for StrError<'a>{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        // Delegate to the Display impl for `&str`:
        self.0.fmt(f)
    }
}

fn foo() -> Result<String, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err(Box::new(StrError("Error...")))
}
```

This code compiles, and is basically exactly what `impl Into<Box<dyn Error>> for &str` does under the hood :)

Comment: Thanks man, that solves the issue with the code. I will need to read more into RUST to fully understand the inner workings but this fix works as expected. much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd put that EDIT at the start of your answer and leave the explanation bellow it..

Comment: @JoeClay What if you need to call a variable inside as you would with println {:?} ?

Comment: @Kaluk: You can use the `format!` macro to generate a `String` using the same formatting syntax as `println!`. The `String` can then be converted into a `Box<dyn Error>` in the same way as `&str` can.

Comment: I have a function that uses `Err("Error...".into())` in multiple places, however it's still not working as described in this answer -- it raises an error that "type annotations needed" because "the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `str`". Any idea what could be the issue? It does work when I use `format!("...").into()`