# expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found struct `std::io::Error`?

Tags: rust

I have a function to request an API and need to return an error when the response status is not 200.

I googled a whole day and haven't figured out a good way to avoid compilation error. if someone could give me a hit it would be appreciated.

```
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use hyper::{Client, Body, Method, Request};

async fn request<'a>(&self, function_url:&'a str, body_data:&'static str, method: Method) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>{

        let https = HttpsConnector::new();
        let client = Client::builder().build::<_, hyper::Body>(https);

        let req = Request::builder()
            .method(method)
            .uri(url)
            .header("content-type", "application/json")
            .body(Body::from(body_data))?;
        let resp = client.request(req).await?;
        
        if resp.status() != 200 {
            let err_resp = Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, resp.status().to_string());
            return Err(err_resp); // compilation error
        }
}
```

```
type mismatch resolving `<impl std::future::Future as std::future::Future>::Output == std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync + 'static)>>`

expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found struct `std::io::Error`

note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync + 'static)>>`
         found enum `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`
```

Comment: The result type of this function is `Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>>` and you return `Err(Error))`. Just put a box around your errors, e.g. `Err(Box::new(err_resp))`.

Comment: @CoronA it gives me a new issue.  `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::boxed::Box<std::io::Error>`

Answer (score 2):

changed the statement fix the compilation error.

```
return Err("Error".into());
```

Here may be the proper answer: [Returning error message to function expecting 'Box<dyn Error>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393250/returning-error-message-to-function-expecting-boxdyn-error)